# Call Method In Windows Service from WCF Service (Self Hosted)

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

C# | .NET 4.5

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, or if I'm structuring this the correct way. I have a Windows Service which self hosts a WCF service. The Windows Service contains all of the logic for an ordering system. The WCF Service allows other systems to call in and place orders. What I would like to do is pass that order that comes in through the WCF service on to the Windows Service for processing.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to accomplish my goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The WCF service should store the order into the database, and a separate process should then process those orders from the database ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the window service is to host WCF service, that is all what it should do (SRP). However, WCF can interact with another Project (say Business service that Process your business rules).

So what I am saying is Windows service only host wcf, wcf service delegates the request to the Business service for processing

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. Thanks for the help!